# Custom ROM on smartwatches

Tags: android, smart-watches

I would like to know if it's possible to flash a smartwatch with non-official ROMs (custom or other brand's officials).

I will buy the Xiaomi Haylou solar and it will be nice to put in Wear OS.

Comment: Welcome! It would be best if you could elaborate this a bit... I think this could be a goood question, but you'll have to focus in a bit more... exactly why do you want a custom ROM? Or, if you already know that you particularly want wear OS on that particular watch, please [edit] to let us know what your precise concerns are... are you unsure how to root?  Whether the OS will work on your particular watch?  We're just going to need more info to help you.  Thanks!